# Are there famous complex constants?

Tags: complex-numbers, constants

Are there any famous constants (like $\pi$ and $e$) that are complex?

More specifically, to rule out trivial complex numbers, are there any famous constants of the form $a+bi$ with $a \neq 0 \wedge b \neq 0$?

Comment: The first non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function: $$\frac{1}{2}+14.13472514\dots i$$ See Plouffe's [database](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/constants/zeta100.html).

Comment: Yes, it is called the [omega-1 constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=omega-1+constant)

Comment: In split-complex numbers $1/2+j/2$ and $1/2-j/2$ are idempotents.

Answer (score 2):

The [j-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series) has several interesting properties, including that
$$
j\left({\frac {1+i{\sqrt{163}}}{2}}\right)=-640320^{3}
$$
where
$$
{\frac {1+i{\sqrt{163}}}{2}} \approx 0.5 + 6.38357266740185i
$$

This is connected to a number of other interesting topics:

- [Heegner numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number)
- [Chudnovsky algorithm for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm)
- [Monstrous moonshine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine)